# Multiple Regex @Pattern's for 1 Field?

Tags: regex, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I was attempted to apply multiple @Pattern annotations to a single field:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9])", message = "Password must contain one digit.")
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])", message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter.")
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z])", message = "Password must contain one uppercase letter.")
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=\S+$)", message = "Password must contain no whitespace.")
private String password;
```

However, I cannot do this.  I want individual messages per violated regex constraint on the password field.  Is this possible?

My alternative is to use JSF 2.0 f:validatorRegex tags.

Comment: You can create your own validation annotation

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the inner `@List` annotation of `@Pattern`:

```
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9])", message = "Password must contain one digit."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])", message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z])", message = "Password must contain one uppercase letter."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=\\S+$)", message = "Password must contain no whitespace.")
})
private String password;
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me  I don't know way but there is something wrong

Comment: regex is not working (jdk 8), Ganov13's solution works though.

Comment: Note that as of Bean Validation 2.0 (and Hibernate Validator 6), `@Pattern` will be a repeatable constraint, i.e. it can be given several times without the explicit `List` annotation.

Comment: This may prove helpful, thumbs up. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gkahq/index.html

Comment: `"(?=.*[0-9])"` why not `".*\d.*"`?

Answer (score 4):

Gunnar's solution won't work for me... '.+' in his regexp seem to be missing.
However, i'm using Michal's patternList and it works like a charm for me. (Play 2.3.x / Ebean-ORM)

```
@Pattern.List({
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9]).+", message = "Password must contain one digit."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z]).+", message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z]).+", message = "Password must contain one upper letter."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-_()/\"\\.,<>~`;:]).+", message ="Password must contain one special character."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=\\S+$).+", message = "Password must contain no whitespace.")
})
@Constraints.Required()
public String password1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into constraint composition.  You would build one annotation per password constraint composed from the @Pattern annotation, and then finally build one composed annotation using the previously defined four.  This would require no extra java code.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-compound

Otherwise, build (with accompanying java code) a custom annotation called @PasswordValidator.

I tend to like composed validators, as it makes the purpose of the validation annotations clear on their purpose, instead of having many disjoint annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I modified Gunnar answer and write composite constraint and this now seems to work correctly on 4 unit tests:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=6, max=45)
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9]).+", message = "Password must contain one digit."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z]).+", message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z]).+", message = "Password must contain one uppercase letter."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-_()/\"\\.,<>~`;:]).+", message ="Password must contain one special character."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=\\S+$).+", message = "Password must contain no whitespace.")
})
@Constraint(validatedBy = {}) // constraints composition
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface StrongPassword {

     String message() default "Password doesn't match bean validation constraints.";
     Class<?>[] groups() default {};
     Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```