# Regex for a string with an optional non-repeating dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate a string in Java to fulfill the following requirements:

- string must be 5-32 characters long
- string can contain

  - letters (a-z),
  - numbers (0-9),
  - dashes (-),
  - underscores (_),
  - and periods (.).
- string mustn't contain more than one period (.) in a row.

Would this regex be be a correct solution?

```
^(?!([^\\.]*+\\.){2,})[\\.a-z0-9_-]{5,32}$
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it in one regex?

Comment: Yes, I need it for bean validation.

Comment: Hint: you dont have to escape any character inside a `[ ]` except for `]`.

Comment: You can have multiple requirements. I think it would be more readable if you used *Size for the length constraint, one *Pattern to check for acceptable chars, another *Pattern to check for "..".  This also allows for different error messages for different violations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225015/multiple-regex-patterns-for-1-field  (By * I mean at-sign -- SO thinks it's addressing a user!)

Comment: Thanks for your hint, Sebastian!

Comment: @SebastianH Actually sometimes `-` needs to be escaped, or placed at place where it will not be part of character range. But yes, generally what you said is true :)

Comment: In this case you only have one viable restraint, the dot. No need to validate the entire string with a lookahead each time. Its costly and inefficient. Its better to do it inline via an alternation.

Comment: @sln it's a maximum of 32 chars long. Readability trumps efficiency here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, You can use this regex to block 2 periods in input:

```
^(?!([^.]*\\.){2})[.a-z0-9_-]{5,32}$
```

If you want to block 2 consecutive dots then use:

```
^(?!.*?\\.{2})[.a-z0-9_-]{5,32}$
```

Comment: This allows for uppercase letters, not sure the OP wants that

Comment: Nice. I havent seen the `(?! )` part of regex before this.

Comment: `"a.a..a".matches("^(?![^.]*\\.{2})[.a-z0-9_-]{5,32}$")` returns `true` :/ Change `(?![^.]*\\.{2})` to `(?!.*\\.{2})` to let negative-look-ahead match also `a.a` before `..`

Answer (score 1):

I love regular expressions, but for reasons of readability and maintainability, I think they should be kept simple wherever possible, and that means using them for what they're good at, and using other features of your language/environment where appropriate.

In the comments you say this is for bean validation. You could validate your field with multiple simple annotations:

```
@Size(min=5,max=32)
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9-_.]*$", 
             message = "Valid characters are a-z, 0-9, -, _, ."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "^((?!\.{2}).)*$", 
             message = "Must not contain a double period")
})
private String myField;
```

Also bear in mind that you can write custom constraints in Java.

... and of course in other contexts the same applies:

```
boolean isValid(String s) {
    return s.length() >= 5 &&
           s.length() <= 32 &&
           s.matches("^[a-z0-9-_.]*$") &&
           !s.contains("..")
}
```

Comment: What _readability_ issue are you talking about? Regular expressions are code, format it like code. **[RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com)**.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 #   "^(?:[0-9a-z_-]|\\.(?!\\.)){5,32}$"  

 ^ 
 (?:
      [0-9a-z_-] 
   |  \.
      (?! \. )
 ){5,32}
 $
```