# Multiple @Pattern behaving like OR operation

Tags: java, regex, url, bean-validation

From [Multiple Regex @Pattern's for 1 Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225015/multiple-regex-patterns-for-1-field) I see how to add multiple patterns, but those are acting as an AND operation.

Is there any way to apply an OR type?

I want to check for an URL pattern and in this sense there are two possiblities:
- domain based
- IP address based

Both are similar but different so I want to include two patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Following the example post on the link you provided, you could leverage regex `OR`, so instead of putting multiple patterns working like `AND` like this:

```
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9])", message = "Password must contain one digit."),
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])", message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter.")
})
private String password;
```

You could change it to use one single pattern with regex alternation working as OR:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])", message = "Password is invalid")
private String password;
```

I cannot test this code since I don't have a project, but I just use the alternation patterns that works in all regex engines.

Comment: I've also thought on your approach but as the regexs are quite long, I was looking for something more "clean". thanks anyway.

Comment: @jlanza well, that's a different question related to how to shorten a regex. If the answers posted in this question solve your issue, then you should mark your question as resolved and open a new one. Related to shorten your regex, then you could use then this one `(?=.*([0-9]|[a-z]))`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question was generally related to regex OR and you answered correctly. With my comment I was just saying the this was already in my plans, but I was looking for a Pattern.List but with OR included in it, so I can get different messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to write a composed constraint, eg *MyURLPattern* which internally uses the Hibernate specific feature of "[Boolean composition of constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-boolean-constraint-composition)". In this case you need to also add the `@ConstraintComposition(OR)` annotation to your composing constraint.

The caveat is that this solution won't be portable between Bean Validation providers.